# How to Build Durable, DIY Capacitive Sliders for a Custom Macro Pad?

Tags: resistance, capacitance, potentiometer, user-interface

I'm working on a custom macro pad project and I'm planning to include three 50mm long sliders. I'm leaning towards capacitive sliders due to their suitability for my design, but I'm flexible on the materials. I'm not overly concerned with precision since I plan to calibrate them individually in software. However, I do want these sliders to be durable and resist wear over time.

Could anyone provide a way to construct DIY capacitive sliders, especially those that offer good durability?

Comment: In the past, I've actually used `free carpet samples` as a way of providing reliable long-term friction. Use that as a segue into your own thoughts about how to do it. (In my case, it was about providing resistance to a 70 kg sliding pocket door rolling on an I-beam and a pair of 600 lb rollers. Still working perfectly to this very day, more than 10 years later!!) Mechanical design like this is actually fun. Enjoy the process!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way for capacitive sliders would be to design the sliders on a normal pcb. Then put a thin foil over it. You can use many materials for this, as long as the foil is not conductive. You can also coat the foil, as long as the coating is not conductive.

If you don't glue the foil immediately, you can try what combination provides the best feel for your application.

Most plastic sheets with very few mm thickness should work as well. The roughness from manufacturing, printing or sanding should hold up long enough as well. ABS works. I am not sure about the longterm surface robustness of softer plastics like PLA for example.

You could also cut the slider sensors from copper tape and glue them to a foil. Then wire them to your circuit for capacitive sensors. This way you can try things out without creating a pcb. Later you can adapt this for a pcb. Be aware that the performance will change a bit depending on the layout and due to the pcb material.

Answer (score 2):

> Could anyone provide a way to construct DIY capacitive sliders, especially those that offer good durability?

I'd put them on layer 2 of a 4-layer PCB, or a very thin 2-layer PCB, with an open window on layer 1. The top layer of laminate acts as a mechanical cover, bonded to the capacitive sensing copper, and to the underlying substrate.

Silkscreen legend on the top of the PCB can then be quite a durable means of labeling active areas, and there's a reasonably wide selection of soldermask colors to choose from.